# « carpe diem » en français

Tags: traduction, latin

En français courant peut-on employer l'expression latine *carpe diem* ou pas ? Est-ce mieux d'utiliser une interprétation française, p. ex. jouir, profiter de l'instant présent ? Peut-on employer la version anglaise mais quelque peu francisée, à savoir, seize the day => saisir le jour ?

Comment: Si tu as pour but de donner l'impression de connaître une expression *sophistiquée*, pourquoi pas ? Cela dit, je préférerais dix fois plus dire "*tirer le meilleur parti de tout ce que la vie a à nous offrir*" ou "*profiter pleinement de ce que la vie a à nous offrir*" ou quelque chose du genre.

Comment: Merci ! Saisir le jour (selon seize the day) semble pas français ?

Comment: Je trouve que votre commentaire mérite le statut de réponse:-)!

Comment: "Saisir le jour" pourrait être remplacé par "Saisir l'instant présent"

Comment: Personnellement, je n'ai jamais entendu "saisir le jour" utilisé de cette façon dans une conversation avec un locuteur natif. Je me sens plus à l'aise avec "*embrasser la vie telle qu'elle est*", par exemple. Un nom comme "occasion" fonctionne mieux comme complément d'objet direct du verbe "saisir": "*saisir chaque jour l'occasion de faire quelque chose*". Le verbe "saisir" signifie prendre rapidement ce qui vient d'apparaître sous nos yeux ; "un jour entier" semble trop long pour saisir instantanément.

Comment: "Carpe diem" en latin me semble suffisamment connu pour être utilisé tel quel en français courant. La traduction "Cueille le jour" est communément utilisée. J'utiliserais donc plutôt celle-ci.
 
Quant à "Embrasser la vie telle qu'elle est" etc. , ce ne sont pas des traductions, mais des expressions ayant le même sens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vu les commentaires et l'article sur le site [Expression](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/carpe-diem.php),  je me permets de répondre.

« Carpe diem » peut bien être employé en français, même lors des échanges avec ceux qui n'ont pas étudié le latin, car c'est assez connu.

Synonymes

> Tirer le meilleur parti / profiter pleinement de tout ce que la vie a à nous offrir
>
> Profiter bien du moment / du jour présent

Comment: C'est une réponse bien optimiste. J'ai bien peur qu'une majorité de Français, jeunes ou moins jeunes, ignore la signification de *carpe diem*...

Comment: d'un autre côté, "le cercle des poètes disparus" a popularisé l'expression, et elle est plus utilisée que sa traduction littérale (cueille le jour)

Comment: @radouxju popularisé auprès des "happy few"...

Comment: @Laure A en croire Wikipedia, le film a quand même été 5ème au box office de 1989. Je conviens que c'est peut être d'une autre génération, mais ce film avait bcp fait parler de lui. Ceci étant dit, "hakuna matata" est sans doute plus connu par la génération suivante (même si la signification est un peu différente).