# Do it while you can or “Strike while the iron is hot” in French

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

How to correctly communicate or express these timely sayings in French? "Do something while the conditions are right" or "Seize the opportunity when it presents itself"

Is this acceptable?  Faites-le tant que vous le pouvez

Comment: For those that aren't into metal-working, this phrase (and the equivalent French phrase below) relates to welding two pieces of iron using a hammer and anvil. Hammer-welding requires working with iron at a critical temperature - it must be hot enough to be workable but not so hot that it bends under its own weight. Not hot enough and you get a "cold weld" that may have a slight surface bonding but which will fail under any load. Too hot and...well, let's just say that being spattered with semi-molten iron does not improve one's day. And you get *one* strike with the hammer - no second chances.

Comment: I know it's not French, but would I be right to assume that 'Carpe Diem' would be recognised by French speakers?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica No worries, [metalworking](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/25204/25619) is within all of us. Very interesting btw. //JeffUK, see [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/30598/25619).

Comment: @JeffUK - well, a lot of English speakers recognize "carpe diem" because knowledge of bits of Latin is pretty common, so I would expect that French speakers would as well.

Answer (score 17):

The [very same metaphor](https://www.expressio.fr/expressions/battre-le-fer-quand-il-est-chaud) exists in French since at least the 14<sup>th</sup> century and is still in common usage:

> *Il faut battre le fer tant qu'il est chaud.*

The preposition might be ***tandis***, ***quand***, ***pendant***, or ***tant***.

***Pendant*** was most common in the 20<sup>th</sup> century but ***tant*** seems to take a small lead in recent years.

[image]

Your attempt *Faites-le tant que vous le pouvez* doesn't convey the same meaning. It's more like "Do it as long as you are able to do it."

You might say instead:

> *Faire quelque chose lorsque les conditions s'y prêtent.*

> *Profiter d'une / saisir une occasion<sup>2</sup> quand elle se présente.*

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Instead of ***occasion***, the word ***opportunité*** is often used to translate "opportunity" but is sometimes considered an anglicism even while this meaning already existed in French [(See the OQLF)](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3526).</sub>

Comment: The most idiomatic version of this expression is "battre le fer **pendant** qu'il est chaud". That's how I have always heard it or used it myself in France.

Comment: @Evargalo The preposition is indeed not fixed in the idiom but *tant*, *pendant* and *quand* are all definitely equally idiomatic while *tandis* is behind.

Comment: And the same metaphor exists in German, too. Although I had hoped for something more romantic from the French, like "Kiss the girl while the night is young" or so ;-). But then it's probably just that we are watching Mrs. Maisel ...

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica This metaphor exists in Italian, Spanish, Polish, Bulgarian, Russian, Arabic, Turkish, Hebrew, Chinese... Perhaps would it be shorter to list the languages that do not use it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The dictionary *Le Petit Robert 2006* gives a French idiom (under the entry "battre") that corresponds exactly with the English "strike the iron while it's hot":

> *Battre le fer pendant qu'il est chaud*: profiter sans tarder d'une situation propice.

In other words: taking advantage of a favourable situation without delay.

Answer (score 0):

Also, "l'occasion fait le larron" is what is as close as "Do something while the conditions are right" I can think of. The meaning is to seize opportunity while it stands

Comment: That expression does not mean what you probably think it means; it is more specific since larron means thief. See e.g. [linternaute.fr](http://www.linternaute.fr/proverbe/530/l-occasion-fait-le-larron/).